# Can you gives a good concepts on how mobile app are built by comparing with web application

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

I want to create an android application using react native, by now I can create a user interface, but I'm still looking for knowledge or answers to my questions that I haven't been able to find on google in an understandable style.

For example, if you want to create a website, there is a frontend and a backend, for a dynamic web application.
There are several languages ​​and frameworks for creating web applications. What about the mobile app side? For example, in web application there are sessions, cookies, authentication and more used in hiding certain pages from unauthorized users, fetching data and inserting it into the database, redirecting user while saving sessions etc.

Are these also available on the mobile application? How are made which backend language , which database, how are deployed, can you explain with real examples or redirect me on the blog with details and the entire flow of the mobile application development, especially by using react native.

In short, you can explain by comparing between mobile and web Application development.

`<Hello/>`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. These types of questions are not allowed unfortunately - it's very broad and will degrade into opinion-based answers. This forum is geared towards concrete answers for specific technical questions. See [ask] at your convenience

Answer (score 0):

There are many backend frameworks to use with mobile Apps. Some are given below

1. Firebase:

Firebase is a comprehensive mobile and web app development platform offered by Google. It includes features like authentication, real-time database, cloud storage, and cloud functions.

2. Node.js with Express.js: (good choice if you are familiar with JavaScript)

Node.js is a popular JavaScript runtime, and Express.js is a lightweight web application framework for Node.js. Together, they provide a powerful and flexible backend solution. They are well-suited for building RESTful APIs to serve data to Android apps.

3. Django: (good choice if you are familiar with Python)

Django is a high-level Python web framework known for its simplicity and robustness. It includes many built-in features like authentication, database management (using Django ORM), and an admin panel.

4. Spring Boot: (good choice if you are familiar with Java)

Spring Boot is a popular Java-based framework for building web and mobile applications. It's known for its scalability and extensive ecosystem of libraries and tools.

5. ASP.NET Core: (good choice if you are familiar with C# and .NET technologies)

ASP.NET Core is a cross-platform, high-performance framework for building modern, cloud-based, and internet-connected applications.